# Printing consecutive numbers in a guessing game (java)?

Tags: java

I created a guessing game in java. It's pretty simple: the computer chooses a random number, the the user gets to choose whether they want 5, 10, or 20 chances to guess that number. After each guess, the program will tell them whether their guess is higher or lower than the magic number. If they guess the number, they get a congratulations message and they're asked if they want to play again. If they don't guess the number, they also get a message and are asked if they want to play again. One thing I would like to add to my code that I can't seem to figure out...
When the user guesses the magic number I would like to do something like this after the congratulations message:

Congratulations, bob! You guessed the magic number in 6 guesses.

You did not use these guesses:

7

8

9

10

I tried this, which I quickly realized didn't make any sense, but from here I am stuck.

```
System.out.println("You did not use these guesses: "+ (i-numberOfGuesses));
```

How should I go about including this? I would prefer not to use an array.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass 
{
  public static void main(String [] args)  
  {
     final String SENTINEL = "no"; 
     int guess;
     String playAgain;
     int numberOfGuesses;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );


      System.out.print( " Enter your name: ");
      String name = scan.next();


      System.out.print(" Would you like to try to guess a number? (Yes or No):");
      String answer = scan.next();

      while(!answer.equals(SENTINEL)){

        if (answer.equals("yes"))
        System.out.print("How many guesses would you like? (5, 10, 20): ");
            do {
            numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();

            if (numberOfGuesses == 5 || numberOfGuesses == 10 || numberOfGuesses == 20 )
                break;
            System.out.print("How many guesses would you like? (5,10,20): ");
            } while (true);

            Random random = new Random();

            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;


           {
          for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfGuesses ; i++){
   System.out.print("Enter guess #"+i+": ");
   guess = scan.nextInt();

   if (guess > randomNumber && guess <= 100)
      System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is greater than the magic number.");

   else if (guess < randomNumber && guess > 0)
      System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is less than the magic number.");

   else if (guess == randomNumber){
      System.out.println("Congratulations, "+name+"! You guessed the magic "
              + "number in "+i+" guesses.");
      System.out.println("You did not use these guesses: "+ (i-numberOfGuesses));
      break;
 }
   else 
       i--;

   if (i == numberOfGuesses)
        System.out.println("Sorry, " + name+", you did not guess the magic "
                + "number, " + randomNumber + ", in "+ numberOfGuesses + " tries.");

          }

         System.out.print("Would you like to try to guess a number? (Yes or No):");
     answer = scan.next();
} 

            }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should replace your proposed (but incorrect) line of code with this loop:

```
    if (i != numberOfGuesses) {
      System.out.println("You did not use these guesses: ");
      for (int j = i + 1; j <= numberOfGuesses; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
      }
    }
```

Also, you have a bug: if you answer yes in the beginning, everything's fine and you play the game. But if you answer Yes (as proposed in the question) or any other text, it waits for another input and when you do input something and press enter, it continues to the game. So, if you enter "No", press enter, enter 1, press enter it will still play.